# How do I get value from HTML select in angular

Tags: angular

I try to get value from HTML select from template variable but it doesn't work.
I have a select in my app component and I want to get his value at the beginning and every time when his value changes.

This is my formula, in `app.component.html`

```js
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" *ngIf="showSelect" #f="ngForm">
    <select class="custom-select" id="service" #serviceSelect (select)="service = serviceSelect.value" >
        <option *ngFor = "let service of listeServices" value="{{service.id}}">{{service.nom}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And this is my `ngAfterViewInit` function :

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.service);
}
```

The only thing I get for the moment is `undefined`.

Comment: Use ngModel to create two-way data binding to be used with HTML select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngAfterViewInit` runs only once in the lifecycle of a component, ie once the view is initialised hence you are getting `undefined` since there is no selection happening. Suggested change to your code below for your mentioned use case:

**app.component.html**

```
<select class="custom-select" id="service" #serviceSelect (change)="setSelection(serviceSelect.value)" >
        <option *ngFor = "let service of listeServices" value="{{service.id}}">{{service.nom}}</option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public setSelection(selectedValue: any): void {
    this.service = selectedValue;
    //do more if needed;
}
```